# Como alterar de character para Date, mantendo a forma de apresentação das Horas? (R)

Tags: r, data, dataframe

eu precisei separar uma coluna de uma tabela em Data e hora. Para isso usei o seguinte comando:

```
Dados <- Dados %>% separate(data,
                          into = c("Data","Hora"),
                          sep = " ")
```

O resultado foi o seguinte:

```
structure(list(Data = c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", 
"2018-01-01", "2018-01-01"), Hora = c("00:00:00", "00:15:00", 
"00:30:00", "00:45:00", "01:00:00"), class = "data.frame")
```

Todavia, a coluna Hora ficou no formato "character" e eu precisava que ficasse no formato "Date". Também gostaria que aparecesse somente horas e minutos nos dados, tipo "00:15".
Para mudar de formato, utilizei o seguinte comando:

```
Dados <- Dados %>% 
  mutate(Data = as_date(Data),
         Hora = hms(Hora))
```

Com isso, o formato de Hora passou para "Date", mas a forma de apresentação dos dados mudou e não consegui retirar os segundos. Vejam o resultado:

```
Dados <-
structure(list(Data = structure(c(17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
17532), class = "Date"), Hora = new("Period", .Data = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), year = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    day = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), hour = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1), minute = c(0, 
    15, 30, 45, 0))), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Resumidamente, quando a hora era no formato "character", o horário de meia noite e quinze, aparecia "00:15:00", mas depois que realizei a modificação para "Date" passou a aparecer "15M 0S". Portanto, gostaria de saber se é possível mudar para o formato "Date", mas mantendo a forma de apresentação anterior e sem os segundos? O que eu gostaria é que no formato "Date" fosse apresentado meia noite e quinze dessa forma: "00:15"

Comment: Tanto quanto eu saiba, o que está a pedir não é possível com o método `print` para objetos de classe `"POSIXct"` (os objetos de classe `"Date"` não têm horas). As horas só são apresentadas assim se forem de classe `"character"`. A `Hora` é uma coluna de classe S4 `"Period"` definida no pacote `lubridate`. Corra `str(Dados$Hora)` para ver como é. Para ter as horas como quer talvez `format(Dados$Data + Dados$Hora, "%H:%M")`.

Comment: Veja se o exemplo o é útil https://ideone.com/EoC0Wr

Comment: Cristiano. Modificar a forma de exibição dos dados, por exemplo usando Xtable, seria uma solução plausivel ou seria uma solução overkill?

Answer (score -3):

Olá,

Infelizmente não será possível visualizar o tempo no formato desejado garantindo que ele ainda se comporte como um marcador temporal, seja do tipo `Period`, como no seu caso quando você converteu de texto para `Period` usando a função `hms`, seja uma data formal mesmo. Esse tipo de apresentação de hora do dia usando a notação "HH:MM" só é possível se for feita em texto a partir de uma data nos formatos precisos do R básico tais como `Date` e `POSIXct`. Tipicamente é mais fácil fazer esse tipo de coisa mantendo disponível na tabela a data completa em `POSIXct` com data, hora, minuto e segundo e depois converter pros formatos de apresentação mais conveninentes usando a função `format`. Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dados <-
  structure(list(
    Data = c(
      "2018-01-01",
      "2018-01-01",
      "2018-01-01",
      "2018-01-01",
      "2018-01-01"
    ),
    Hora = c("00:00:00", "00:15:00",
             "00:30:00", "00:45:00", "01:00:00")
  )) |>
  as_tibble() |>
  mutate(
    data_completa = paste(Data, Hora) |>
      ymd_hms(),
    hora_apresentacao = data_completa |>
      format(
        "%H:%M"
      )
  )
```